# Import Error when trying to import models from custom app

Tags: python, django, import, relative-import

I have a django project and I am trying to import a model from my app website to my App_2.

That is more or less my folder structure:

- website

  - website
  - app1

    - models.py
    - views.py
      ....
  - app2

    - models.py
    - views.py
      ....

Now, in my views.py (App2) I'd like to import a method from models.py (app1). The following problems occur:

1. When trying `from app1 import models`

`ModuleNotFoundError:No module named 'website.app'`

2. When trying 'from website.app1 import models'

`ValueError: attempted relative import beyond top-level package`

3. When trying `from ..app1 import models``

`ValueError: attempted relative import beyond top-level package`

So relative and absolute imports fail... I have the feeling I am overlooking something.

Any help is appreciated, thank you.

Comment: the first one is the correct one and should work. Do you have an import with `heatbeat_website.analytics`? does this module exist? if so in which file?

Comment: thanks for the reply. I made a mistake in the error display. It would be ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'website.app'. I adjusted the question. Sorry

Comment: what are the imports in the models.py in `app1.models`

Comment: hm, after multiple times restarting my server the first command works now... Or let's rather say it doesn't throw me an error anymore. Yet, Pycharm is still telling me ```Unresolved reference 'app1```. I guess that can be ignored though?!

Comment: @ArpitSolanki thanks so much for the quick help mate!!